# How to check java-script,which is in JSP function output in java servlet file or scriptlets

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, web

Here my aim is to submit this form to servlet, which will built process DB query. I have validated the mail using javascript. Normally when i click submit it will validate email and prompt user for false format of mail and simultaneously  pass to servlet all information which make query and insert into DB. But the validation of mail gives false mail.
So how can i pass javascript function value to servlet to to validate first and then built query and insert into database?
We can use Scriptlet also.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function ValidateEmail(inputText)
    {
        var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
        {
            document.text1.focus();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
            document.text1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

jsp:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/><br/> 
<button type="submit" name="xyz" onclick=ValidateEmail(email) class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
```

Provide code snippet for solution.

Comment: SO is not really a code writing service. You write the code and we help you solve problems that you cannot solve in your own code.

Comment: Are you saying you wanted to submit the form or invoke servlet even when front end email validation fails?

Comment: Yes, exaclty @ notionquest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare an input type hidden field within form tag and give it id and name attribute like

```
<input type="hidden" id="demo" name="valid">
```

Next store value true or false in a js variable and put that variable value in hidden field that we earlier declared like

```
<script>
function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
var val;
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
{
document.text1.focus();
val=true;

}
else
{
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
document.text1.focus();
val=false;

}
document.getElementById("demo").value=val;
}
```

After this in servlet declare a variable and get value from jsp of hidden field by its name attribute like

```
String value=request.getParameter("valid");
```

Comment: Hi Miral, good and detailed first answer! In the future you might also use more indendation in your code samples to make it easier to understand for the rest of us. In addition you might want to use inline quoting when referencing code bits in your sentences, such as when referring to `id` instead of just writing id.